# Getting error: V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to run my application but i can't run due to this error showing

```
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 82941
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

And I'm also tried this steps but it's not helped me

Steps:

- Uninstall the app from your mobile/emulator.
- Then go to the File option in the main menubar in the Android Studio.
- Then click on Invalidatecasha/restart.

How can I clear my errors?

Comment: There's quite a lot of potential duplicate questions to choose from: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=V%2FFA%3A+Inactivity%2C+disconnecting+from+the+service

Comment: Can you show us the code that produces that output?